# Optimizing a very large LINQ query

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I need to write a/multiple LINQ queries to get some data that I will display for a report.

The tables I need to use are StaffingResources, StaffingForecastEvents (which link a StaffingResource to a Project), and StaffingForecasts (which link to StaffingForecastEvents and contain hours for each week). Each StaffingResource can have 0-many StaffingForecastEvents, and a StaffingForecastEvent can have 0-many StaffingForecasts.

I need to write LINQ query that, for each Resource, will contain all of the projects they have ForecastEvents on, and for each Project all of their Forecasts for a given date range (which is either a 12 weeks or 6 months). Here is what I have so far, and it is running pretty slow.

```
// Get date ranges
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
var startDate = range == (int)RangeTypes.WEEKLY 
    ? DateTime.Today.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Monday - DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek) 
    : new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);
for (var i = 0; i < (range == (int)RangeTypes.WEEKLY ? 4 : 6); i++)
{
    dates.Add(range == (int)RangeTypes.WEEKLY ? startDate.AddDays(i * 7) : startDate.AddMonths(i));
}
var endDate = dates[dates.Count-1];

// Get resources
var resources = from r in context.StaffingResourceDatas
                where r.EmployeeId.HasValue
                   && (resourceIds.Count == 0 || resourceIds.Contains(r.EmployeeId.Value))
                   && (resourceDivisions.Count == 0 || resourceDivisions.Contains(r.ResourceDivisionId))
                   && (resourceTitles.Count == 0 || resourceTitles.Contains(r.ResourceTitleId))
                   && (resourceLocations.Count == 0 || resourceLocations.Contains(r.ResourceLocationId))
                   && (supervisors.Count == 0 || supervisors.Contains(r.ReportsToId))
                   && (showAllResources || (!showAllResources && !exclusionList.Contains(r.ResourceTitleId)))
                join fe in context.StaffingForecastEvents
                   .Include(x => x.StaffingForecasts)
                   .Include(x => x.StaffingUser)
                   .Include(x => x.StaffingUser1)
                   .Include(x => x.StaffingForecasts.Select(y => y.StaffingUser))
                   .Include(x => x.StaffingForecasts.Select(y => y.StaffingUser1))
                 on r.ResourceId equals fe.ResourceId into g1
                from fe in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join p in context.StaffingProjectDatas on fe.JobNumber equals p.JobNumber into g2
                from p in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                group new { ForecastEvent = fe, Project = p } by r into g3
                select new
                {
                    ResourceId = g3.Key.ResourceId,
                    Name = g3.Key.ResourceName,
                    Title = g3.Key.ResourceTitle,
                    Division = g3.Key.ResourceDivision,
                    Location = g3.Key.ResourceLocation,
                    AvailableDate = g3.Key.AvailableDate,
                    SupervisorEmail = g3.Key.ManagerEmail,
                    Projects = g3.Where(p => p.ForecastEvent != null).Select(p => new
                    {
                        JobNumber = p.ForecastEvent.JobNumber,
                        Description = p.Project.ProjectDescription,
                        Name = p.Project.ProjectName,
                        Division = p.Project.ProjectDivision,
                        ProjectManager = p.Project.PMName,
                        Notes = p.ForecastEvent.Notes,
                        LogDate = p.ForecastEvent.LogDate,
                        LogUser = p.ForecastEvent.StaffingUser.Name,
                        AckDate = p.ForecastEvent.AcknowledgeDate,
                        AckUser = p.ForecastEvent.StaffingUser1 != null ? p.ForecastEvent.StaffingUser1.Name : null,
                        Usages = dates.Select(d => new
                        {
                            Date = d,
                            Hours = (range == (int)RangeTypes.WEEKLY)
                               ? (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date == d).Any() ? p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date == d).Sum(f => f.Hours) : 0)
                               : (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date.Year == d.Year && f.Date.Month == d.Month).Any() ? p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date.Year == d.Year && f.Date.Month == d.Month).Sum(f => f.Hours) : 0),
                            LogDate = (range == (int)RangeTypes.WEEKLY)
                                // Get acknowledge or log date for week
                               ? (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date == d).Any()
                                   ? ((p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Date == d).AcknowledgeDate) != null)
                                       ? (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Date == d).AcknowledgeDate)
                                       : (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Date == d).LogDate)
                                   : null)
                                // Get acknowledge or log date for most recent forecast for month
                               : (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date.Year == d.Year && f.Date.Month == d.Month).Any()
                                   ? ((p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date.Year == d.Year && f.Date.Month == d.Month).OrderByDescending(f => f.LogDate).FirstOrDefault().AcknowledgeDate) != null)
                                       ? (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date.Year == d.Year && f.Date.Month == d.Month).OrderByDescending(f => f.LogDate).FirstOrDefault().AcknowledgeDate)
                                       : (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date.Year == d.Year && f.Date.Month == d.Month).Max(f => f.LogDate))
                                   : null),
                            LogUser = (range == (int)RangeTypes.WEEKLY)
                                // Get acknowledge or log user for week
                               ? (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date == d).Any()
                                   ? ((p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Date == d).AcknowledgeDate) != null)
                                       ? (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Date == d).StaffingUser1.Name)
                                       : (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Date == d).StaffingUser.Name)
                                   : null)
                                // Get acknowledge or log user for most recent forecast for month
                               : (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date.Year == d.Year && f.Date.Month == d.Month).Any()
                                   ? ((p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date.Year == d.Year && f.Date.Month == d.Month).OrderByDescending(f => f.LogDate).FirstOrDefault().AcknowledgeDate) != null)
                                       ? (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date.Year == d.Year && f.Date.Month == d.Month).OrderByDescending(f => f.LogDate).FirstOrDefault().StaffingUser1.Name)
                                       : (p.ForecastEvent.StaffingForecasts.Where(f => f.Date.Year == d.Year && f.Date.Month == d.Month).OrderByDescending(f => f.LogDate).FirstOrDefault().StaffingUser.Name)
                                   : null),
                        })
                    })
                };
```

I will also need to get totals for each resource for each date range.

I feel like the bottleneck is probably with all the "Where"s when looping through the dates, but I don't know what else to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Might be time to turn this into a view.

Comment: Linq is not necessarily always better than SQL. Is there any particular reason you might not consider converting this to a view, stored procedure, or table-valued function?

Comment: This will be a priceless debugging experience for you.

Comment: Also, can you please post the SQL that is being generated?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are doing joins instead of using Navigation properties?

Comment: I can see why this would perform slow.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point you can split it up into several expressions using `IQueryable<T>`. It would also help you make your where clauses simpler. That would look something like:

```
var queryable = context.StaffingResourceDatas.Where(r => r.EmployeeId.HasValue);
if(resourceIds.Any())
{
    queryable = queryable.Where(r => resourceIds.Contains(r.EmployeeId.Value))
}
```

Notice that this will generate SQL related to filtering by resourceIds only if resourceIds is not empty, thus potentially saving the overhead of checking it in the generated query itself.

You can write the rest of the filters similarly to this one. Also notice that query won't get executed until you call `ToList()` on it. So you can keep adding as many clauses as you like, until you're done constructing it.

But at the end of the day you might want to consider writing this one in raw SQL because it's just, you know, gigantic.